# Unix - batch file to unzip folder with specific name

Tags: bash, shell, unix, unzip

I need a batch script for unix but I don't know it very well.

I have folder A and his subfolder

```
A\a1\b\c\file.zip
A\a2\b\c\otherFile.zip
A\a3\b\c\thirdFile.zip
```

Each zip file contains a xml file and a text file

The script have to do 2 things:

1. unzip all the zip files that are in all folder named 'c' of all sub
   folder of 'A' ; the unzipped files should stay in the same folder in
   which was the zip
2. all the unzipped files that have xml extension have to been renamed

someone can help me?

Thank you very much

Comment: i tried only the unzip and the rename without loop on the subfolder but it doesnt' work. this is the code:   

for i in *.zip; do
    mkdir "home/A/a1/b/c/"
    cd "home/A/a1/b/c/"
    unzip "../$i"
    for j in *.xml; do
        mv "$j" "$j.tmp"
    done

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
    #find the folder 'c' and unzip all zip files
    for folder in `find ./A -name c -type d`; do unzip $folder/data.zip -d $foler; done

    #find all .xml files and change the extension to .edefg
    for file in `find ./A -name *.xml -type f`; do  mv "$file" "${file%.xml}.edefg"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You must go to all dir's.
Would be something like

```
find A -type d -name c | while read dir; do
   cd ${dir} || continue
   unzip -u *.zip
   call_rename_xml_function
   cd - # not needed in bash where this code is performed in a subshell
done
```

EDIT: Added -u flag for when the script is called twice.

Comment: it works but if I run the script 2 times, it copies folder in other folder. For example, second time I run the script, i found a copy of folder a1 (with all his subfolders) in folder a2... do you know why?

Comment: How did you implement call_rename_xml_function?

Comment: I didn't...for the moment I tried only the unzip.
I made same test...the problem I told you happens only if the folders already contains the unzipped flles. could it be an overwrite problem? even if i don't understand how it made the copy

Comment: I'm guessing with the zip options, do you have files including path's in it? You can try `unzip -j *.zip`. Or start debugging be replacing the `unzip *.zip` line with `echo "In $PWD I have *.zip"` and look if that shows what we expect.

Comment: no, all the zip files contain one txt and one xml, both empty. I noticed that when it made the copy create a file instead of folder c. I try to explain myself better with an example: the initial structure is A\a1\b\c\file.zip but when i found the copy of folder a1 in a2\b\c, b folder in a1 didn't contain folder c but a txt file named c so at the end the situation in a2 is A\a2\b\c\file.zip + unzipped xml&txt file and   A\a2\b\c\a1\b\c.txt

Comment: When you unzip files that already exist, zip wants to know what you want.
I should have added the zip-flag -u to avoid user interaction.
Somehow things got messed up with the user input wanted.